# Handling dynamic JSON schema decoding

Tags: go, parsing, json-rpc

I have a Go HTTP client which sends/parses `JSON-RPC` requests.

HTTP POST Request :

```
[
   {"id":"1", "method":"action1","params":[]},
   {"id":"2", "method":"action2","params":[]},
   ...
   {"id":"X", "method":"actionX","params":[]}
]
```

HTTP response :

```
[
   {"id":"1", "error":null, "result":{...}},
   {"id":"2", "error":null, "result":{...}},
   ...
   {"id":"X", "error":null, "result":{...}}
]
```

How to handle those payloads where the `result` key is an object with dynamic schema depending on the value of the key `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instruct the json library not to unmarshal the result field by unmarshaling the result into a [`json.RawMessage`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#RawMessage), in this case unmarshal the response into a slice of:

```golang
type result struct{
    ID     string          `json:"id"`
    Err    *string         `json:"error"` // maybe a string?
    Result json.RawMessage `json:"result"`
}
```

Then when you know which ID you are dealing with you can unmarshal `result.ID` into another struct with the structure you expect.

Comment: the super neat stuff is that this type is just a byte slice under the hood `type RawMessage []byte`.